# I can't split my HSV image into channels (H,S,V)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, opencv3.0

Here is the code under Microsoft Visual 2010 C++. It illustrates splitting an HSV image into three channels Hue, Saturation and Value. When executing this program I get:

> program.exe stopped working

```
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "string"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"  
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


 int main(int argc , char** argv)
  {
        Mat img_hsv, img_rgb;
        img_rgb =cvLoadImage("er.jpg", 1);
        cvtColor(img_rgb, img_hsv,CV_RGB2HSV);
        namedWindow("hsv",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow("hsv",img_hsv);


         vector<Mat> channels;
         channels.clear();
         channels.resize(img_hsv.channels());  //resize channels 
         cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[0]);
         namedWindow("Hue", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
         imshow("Hue", channels[0]);

         cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[1]);
         namedWindow("Saturation", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
         imshow("Saturation", channels[1]);

         cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[2]);
         namedWindow("value", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
         imshow("value", channels[2]);
         waitKey(0); }
```

Comment: also not `RGB2HSV` but `BGR2HSV` .

Comment: test that `img_rgb.empty()` isn't true directly after reading/loading the image. cvLoadImage is probably deprecated, try `img_rgb = cv::imread(pathToTheImage)` and still test the `.empty` situation to make sure that the image was loaded sucessfully. Using relative pathes can be tricky, because the working directory isnt always intuitive in windows (visual studio).

Comment: i think the problem is with the split function,so i puted the program in comment from `cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[1])`; till the end and the program was working fine it shows the HSV image and the Hue image but if i uncomment the rest of the program it won't work

Answer (score 2):

[`cv::split(InputArray m, OutputArrayOfArrays mv)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8027f9deee1e42716be8039e5863fbd9) outputs all channels in the output array, so you need only one call

```
cv::split(img_hsv, channels);
```

instead of the three calls

```
cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[0]);
cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[1]);
cv::split(img_hsv, &channels[2]);
```